# How to display records of select query with left join in table using foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, left-join

I have two tables (table A and B). I need to show them in one table, but have an issue with how I to display the records on my table. Please see my sample:

Table A:

```
id   name
1    John
2    Mark
3    Nick`
```

Table b:

```
id     job 
1    Encoder
2
3    Programmer`
```

I made a query to connect the two tables

```
select a.id, a.name, b.job from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.id=a.id
order by a.id;
```

Using codeigniter,

This is the controller:

```
$this->db->select('a.id, a.name, b.job);
$this->db->from('table a');
$this->db->join('table b', 'b.id=a.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('a.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data["view_records"]=$query;
$this->load->view("table_name", $query);
```

This is the view

```
<table id="tablestyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <col width="50">
    <col width="150">
    <col width="150">
    <col width="150">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th><strong>NAME</strong></th>
            <th><strong>JOB</strong></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($view_records->result() as $row) {  ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->a.id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->a.name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->b.job; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Modify" id="btnModify" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" onclick="btnModify('<?php echo $row->a.id; ?>');"/></td>
                </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Model**

```
public function get_user()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select a.id, a.name, b.job from table_a a
        left join table_b b on b.id=a.id
        order by a.id");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['get_user'] = $this->model_name->get_user();

$this->load->view("view_name", $data);
```

**In View**

```
<table id="tablestyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <col width="50">
    <col width="150">
    <col width="150">
    <col width="150">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th><strong>NAME</strong></th>
            <th><strong>JOB</strong></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($get_user as $rowItem) {  ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rowItem['a.id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rowItem['a.name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rowItem['b.job'] ?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Modify" id="btnModify" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" onclick="btnModify('<?php echo $rowItem['a.id'] ?>');"/></td>
                </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```